# Spring: i18n MessageSource is not working for some locales

Tags: java, spring-boot

I've these three documents:

```
messages/exceptions/document
├── document_ca_ES.properties
├── document_en.properties
└── document_es.properties
```

Spring configuration is straightforward:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasenames("messages/exceptions/document");
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
    return messageSource;
}
```

I'm testing that using `curl` commands:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8081/fitxers/raw/b64 \
  -H 'Accept-Language: es' \
  ...
```

Using `Accept-Language: es` or without header works fine:

`Accept-Language: es` locale:

```
{
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Contenido ya existente"
}
```

no `Accept-Language`:

```
{
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Content already exists"
}
```

However, when `Accept-Language: ca_ES` the result is in english:

```
{
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Content already exists"
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you replace the underscore with a dash at both places and try? `ca-es`

Comment: It doesn't work.